# How to show content on WebView

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having problem of showing content on WebView. I got url from API then I try to load like this `webView.loadUrl(url)`. The WebView just shows blank. When I try to open the url on browser and it just downloads an html file.
Question is how can I show the html content on WebView without downloading html file?

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                                 Toast.makeText(this@ChapterPlaybackActivity, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler?, error: SslError?) {
                                 handler!!.proceed()
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                                 Toast.makeText(this@ChapterPlaybackActivity, "Loaded ${view!!.title}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
webView.loadUrl(url)
```

I expected to see some toasts and content on WebView, but still blank

Comment: Anyone can help plz?

Comment: Never mind, I found solutions :)